# jQuery Ajax post data missing after a delay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is really anoying me.

I have a simple HTML form that I'm submitting with jQuery.

```
$("#RecruitmentRequest").submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var formval = $( this ).find(":input:not(:hidden)").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addrec.php",
        data: formval
    });//ajax
});//end submit
```

If load the html and submit the form very quickly then dump the `$_REQUEST` var in my PHP I get a nice looking array of key=>value pairs.
If however I let the page settle for 15 seconds before submitting my form the `$_REQUEST` var is empty!

I have added alerts to the JQ to show the contents of the `formval` var both before and after the ajax call, and lit always ooks OK.

Other jQuery stuff on the page continues to function just fine:

```
$('input:radio[name=bu]').click(function(){
    var unit=$(this).attr('data-unit');
    var newname=$('#rrtbau_exec').attr('data-' + unit);
$('#rrtbau_exec').val(newname);
});//business unit radio click
```

All the jQuery is in a `$(document).ready(function(){...});` container.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you use the browser debugger, do you see the data in the network request?

Comment: do you have more than one form on your page?

Comment: What's this mean "If however I let the page settle for 15 seconds"?

Comment: Hi, I'm working with IE on my company intranet, yes I can see the data in the cars after the .serialise call.  By settle, I simply mean I load then page, and wait for a bit. As the site is on the LAN it loads very quickly. The initial jQuery that hids some Divs runs instantly and the page seems to load in much less than 1 second.

Comment: OK, I am still unsure as to what the problem is, but I've coded around it by adding a lot of debugging to my PHP, then using that info to trace the issues. This allowed me to find the data structure in PHP andsort it out. The data in PHP simply changed and that caused the aparent jQuery issue. I don't have a good explanation of what happened or why, I must have missed a step somewhere though. Thanks for hte input above, it helped me to take a step back and start the debugging again.